# Ошибка в описании конкурса: Лишнее слово “через” в описании выдачи награды

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация

Лишнее слово "через":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом в Транзифексе строка правильная:

[image: скриншот транзифекс]

Видимо, проблема в том, что подставляется в `$timeLeft$`.

Заодно не мешало бы точку поставить в конце предложения.

Comment: Строки подставляемые в `$timeLeft$` жестко заданы в коде для каждого языка. Так же, в коде есть «хак», так как для англоязычной версии «in» (тот, что превращается в «через») перед вставкой вырезается из строки.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky значит нужен ещё один "хак", убирающий и "через" перед вставкой.

Comment: @alexolut проще убрать "через" из переменной.

Comment: @PavelMayorov проще? Уберите.

Comment: @alexolut у меня одинаково нет прав на оба варианта действий.

Comment: @PavelMayorov дело в том, что зашитые в код строки могут поменять только разработчики, а когда они это смогут сделать, даже Николас наверное не знает. Поэтому "проще" тут не очень подходит. Вот "правильнее" было бы правильнее :) Если бы это "через" было в transifex, его не составило бы труда выпилить не привлекая разработчиков, но его там нет. Поэтому нужно либо подстраиваться под реалии, либо ничего не делать, либо как-то активнее пинать разрабов.

Comment: @alexolut так ведь и хак тоже только разработчики могут поставить...

Comment: @PavelMayorov угу, но хак-то не просто так появился в английской версии. И если убрать "через" вообще, то допускаю, что поедет в других местах. Иначе бы они и "in" сразу убрали нормальным (не хак) способом.

Comment: @alexolut Задача внесена в базу дефектов, на сколько я знаю. Когда будет реализована – не известно, к сожалению.

Answer (score 5):

В [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265028?key=236da62d1ef85c8655a0f9a657f03106) исходный текст:

> You have $timeLeft$ to award the bounty

сейчас переведен так:

> У вас осталось $timeLeft$ для присуждения награды.

Если верить [комментарию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3651/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0#comment11901_3651) @NicolasChabanovsky (а не верить, особого смысла нет) и строка "через" жёстко зашита в код, то предлагаю исправить перевод, учитывая эту особенность:

> Возможность присудить награду будет утрачена $timeLeft$. Постарайтесь успеть вовремя.

Хотя это безусловно костыльное решение.

P.S. Утвердил на transifex. Проверяйте вечером в понедельник 10 апреля 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Не нашёл в Transifex строки `через $timeLeft$`. Есть только одна бредовая идея. Рядом есть такая строка:

> Grace period ends in $timeLeft$
>
> Период отсрочки вознаграждения заканчивается через $timeLeft$.

Возможно, движок берёт отсюда время и последнее слово перед временем?

Comment: Либо в этом месте выводится "через через" :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ехал через через через. Видит через - через в через. Сунул через через в через. Через через через через.