# Опечатка в тексте во время периода отсрочки вознаграждения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вопрос с объявленным конкурсом, который закончился, но еще действует период отсрочки вознаграждения содержит лишнее слово **через**.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лишнее слово в тексте:

> Период отсрочки вознаграждения заканчивается **через** через 21 час.

Ссылка на источник:

[Пример периода отсрочки вознаграждения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/645520/189339)

В течение 21 часа - можно увидеть опечатку. До завтрашнего утра или до присуждения вознаграждения.

Comment: [Связанный баг](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3651/176217)

Comment: Строка: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265029?key=8ba9f4764f38b976af0575068d1be0de

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а это что такое? )

Comment: @DenisBubnov строка, в которой есть одно из двух слов «через». Но проблема не в ней, а в вышеуказанном связанном баге.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, просто я там не зарегистрирован был... поэтому спросил. Что с вопросом делать? Удалять?

Comment: Удалять не надо. Надо фиксить :)

Comment: @alexolut, да я бы с удовольствием, но увы, я не знаю как :(

Comment: @DenisBubnov вопрос хороший. Фиксить сами не знаем как, т.к. проблемный код нам недоступен. Только разработчики могут.

Comment: @NickVolynkin исключение "через" из transifex разве не решит проблему?

Comment: @alexolut а вдруг потом второй баг починят и не останется ни одного "через" ?

Comment: @alexolut вообще, наверное лучше исключить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin дилемма: что лучше "через через" или "" :) Мне кажется, что когда (и если) зашитое в код "через" уберут, то просто добавим новый баг с "" и решим его снова через transifex. Вот и всё.

Comment: @alexolut sounds like a plan.

Comment: @NickVolynkin do you have a tool to make an answer from a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю убрать "через" из [упомянутой строки](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265029?key=8ba9f4764f38b976af0575068d1be0de) в transifex и насладиться результатом:

> Период отсрочки вознаграждения заканчивается $timeLeft$.

Дойдут ли руки у разработчиков до выпиливания зашитого в код слова - очень большой вопрос.

Изменения в transifex внесены, для просмотра результата нужно найти вопрос, находящийся в периоде отсрочки вознаграждения. Как это сделать см. вопрос [Как найти вопросы, находящиеся в периоде отстрочки вознаграждения?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5101/)

Comment: Мне же отмечать вопрос как верный только после того, как данная опечатка будет исправлена, верно?

Comment: @DenisBubnov факт исправления бага обычно отмечается меткой [meta-tag:статус-завершено] модератором. Я обычно жду фактического исправления и тогда отмечаю галочкой, но Вы можете поступить как Вам удобнее.