# Как найти вопросы, находящиеся в периоде отстрочки вознаграждения?

Tags: поддержка, поиск, конкурс

[Конкурсные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), для которых время конкурса истекло, но ещё не было присуждено вознаграждение находятся в периоде отсрочки вознаграждения (в справке он сейчас называется "период щедрости"). Этот период длится не более суток.

Как можно найти такие вопросы?

Вопрос возник после публикации бага [Опечатка в тексте во время периода отсрочки вознаграждения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5090/176217).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможный способ поиска основан на факте наличия у таких сообщений подписи следующего вида:

> [image: notice]

За наличие подписи отвечает параметр `hasnotice` в [расширенном поиске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching). При этом такой вопрос должен быть не закрыт и не заблокирован. Получим такой запрос:

> [hasnotice:1 closed:0 locked:0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1%20closed%3A0%20locked%3A0)

Результат поиска по такому запросу будет также содержать вопросы, по которым конкурс ещё активен. Какого-то параметра, чтобы исключить их из поиска, насколько мне известно, на текущий момент не существует. Поэтому нужно вручную сравнить результат поиска со списком конкурсных вопросов, который можно увидеть на соответствующей [вкладке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured).

> [image: конкурсные]

Если кол-во вопросов в выдаче совпадает, то значит вопросов, находящихся в периоде отсрочки вознаграждения сейчас нет.