# Конкурс закончился 5 часов назад. You have через 18 часов to award the bounty

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

Когда заканчивается конкурс, и остаётся *grace period* (не знаю как он называется по-русски), то фраза, означающая сколько осталось часов до его окончания, не переведена. К примеру:

> По данному вопросу был объявлен конкурс с наградой +50 баллов репутации участником Vadim Ovchinnikov; конкурс закончился 5 часов назад. You have через 18 часов to award the bounty

> [image: ошибка локализации в конкурсе]

Comment: О том, как найти подобные вопросы, можно почитать [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5101/176217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я добавил перевод для строки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выгрузки переводов на сайт уведомление будет выглядеть так:

> По данному вопросу был объявлен конкурс с наградой +50 баллов репутации участником Vadim Ovchinnikov; конкурс закончился 5 часов назад. Возможность присудить вознаграждение станет недоступной через N часов.

Если у вас есть замечания к переводу, пожалуйста, оставьте их в комментариях.

Comment: А может сделать текст более дословным? Что-то вроде "У вас есть 18 часов чтобы присудить награду", как думаете?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov увы, мы ограничены элементом «через N часов». Его формулировку изменить невозможно, поэтому приходится подбирать контекст, который будет с ним сочетаться.

Comment: Значит придётся так изворачиваться. Спасибо вам большое. Это в любом случае намного лучше, чем было.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov спасибо _вам_! Если вы заметите другие недочеты в локализации, обязательно сообщите о них на Мете или в чате.

Comment: Хорошо, без проблем.